# How can I add an alias to Apache in XAMPP v3.2.1?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have added an alias in the `httpd.conf` file to access my folder at `localhost/projects` :

```
<IfModule alias_module>

    Alias /projects "C:/Users/Ben/Google Drive/Projects"

    <Directory "C:/Users/Ben/Google Drive/Projects">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>
```

When I try to start Apache in XAMPP 3.2.1 nothing is written to the error.log and Apache fails to start.

Comment: Where did you download XAMPP? It's still in [version](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) [1.8.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP). How did you get version 3.2.1 ?

Comment: Pretty sure he is referring to the version number displayed in the control panel window.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the version number displayed in the control panel. So the latest version of XAMPP 1.8.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

File:
httpd.conf (original)

After of:

```
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
```

Put:

```
<Directory "C:/Users/Ben/Google Drive/Projects">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /projects "C:/Users/Ben/Google Drive/Projects"
```