# Deploying a Flask application using cgi script in Xampp

Tags: python, flask, server, xampp, cgi

I am attempting to deploy a simple [Hello World script](http://flask.pocoo.org/) on XAMMP.

In case the link is removed here is `application.py`:

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

My `applciation.cgi` script is as follows:

```
#!C:/Users/Simon/Documents/Python/Scripts/python.exe
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from application import hello
CGIHandler().run(app)
```

`C:/Users/Simon/Documents/Python/` is the location of my virtual python environment.

I have configured XAMMP (httpd.conf) in the following way:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

This configuration I kept in all cases.

I tried the following as suggested [in the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/cgi/#server-setup):

```
ScriptAlias /Network C:/Users/Simon/Documents/Network/application.cgi
```

This failed and I tried this as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623313/how-can-i-add-an-alias-to-apache-in-xampp-v3-2-1):

```
<Directory "C:/Users/Simon/Documents/Network">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /Network "C:/Users/Simon/Documents/Network"
```

In all cases an `Error 500 Server error!` was returned.

I'm not sure if it's needed but here is the relevant error showing in `access.log`:

```
192.168.0.8 - - [17/Feb/2018:13:21:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 1100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36"
```

*If anything is missing please tell me and I will add it.*

How can I correctly configure my server so that I can run this script?

---

There was  mistake in application.cgi:

```
#!C:/Users/Simon/Documents/Python/Scripts/python.exe
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from application import hello
CGIHandler().run(hello)
```

It is however still returning an error:

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

Comment: have you completed this task?

Comment: @VaibhavkumarChaudhary  Unfortunatly not.  I ended up giving up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported the wrong thing in your CGI script; as a result `app` is not defined. You should be importing that rather than `hello`.

Comment: That was a bad mistake.  I'm getting another error  now: `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.` Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: Now you've changed the wrong thing. You should import `app` and pass it to `run()`.

Comment: Now trying `from application import app`, `CGIHandler().run(app)`.  I'm getting a 404 error (not found error) you could not tell me if I should be using `ScriptAlias /Network C:/Users/Simon/Documents/Network/application.cgi` or the other listed (or both)